# How to say "my experience at place X"?

Tags: usage

How would you say "my experience at X", e.g. "my experience at university". 
Is 「私の大学のけいけん」correct for this usage?

Answer (score 5):

It would be 「[私]{わたし}の[大学]{だいがく}での[経験]{けいけん}」 or 「大学での私の経験」.

You would need to use 「での」 instead of 「の」.

「大学での経験」, without using a pronoun, is just fine as well.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a source?

Comment: @miikaelf l'électeur is a native Japanese speaker, I don't think he has a source prepared.

Comment: Then that is the source, no more needed.